# Pivoting/joining/expanding dataframes based on condition in R

Tags: r, join, pivot-table

I am struggling with the following issue, respectively I am able to make this work with looping over each row of liveDataset and call custom function on the go - but me real dataset is quite huge so I need to do it in "more R way" to avoid looping.

I have tried multiple approaches founded here or somewhere else, still was not able to do what I need.

Here is the data

```
liveDataset <- 
          data.frame(
            Value1 = 
              c(
                100, 110, 115, 108, 90, 95
              ),
            Value2 = 
              c(
                105, 108, 118, 103, 94, 104
              ),
            PredValues = 
              c(
                0.7, 1.6, 1.3, 0.1, 0.4, -0.6
              )
          )

controlDataset <- 
          data.frame(
            Value1 = 
              c(
                98, 111, 114, 109, 85, 95
              ),
            Value2 = 
              c(
                100, 108, 115, 103, 90, 104
              ),
            PredValues = 
              c(
                1, 2, 1, 0.5, -2, -0.3
              )
          )


desiredOutput <- 
          data.frame(
            GroupId =
              c(
                1, 1, 1, 1,
                2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
                4, 4, 4,
                5, 5,
                6, 6
              ),
            Value1 = 
              c(
                100, 98, 85, 95,
                110, 98, 109, 85, 95,
                115, 98, 111, 114, 109, 85, 95,
                108, 98, 85, 
                90, 85,
                95, 85
                
              ),
            Value2 = 
              c(
                100, 103, 90, 104,
                108, 100, 103, 90, 104,
                118, 100, 108, 115, 103, 90, 104,
                103, 100, 90, 
                94, 90,
                104, 90 
                
              ),
            PredValues =
              c(
                0.7, 1, -2, -0.3,
                1.6, 1, 0.5, -2, -0.3,
                1.3, 1, 2, 1, 0.5, -2, -0.3,
                0.1, 1, -2,
                0.4, -2,
                -0.6, -2
                
              )
          )
```

This is just handmade example and there is my explanation/description of the issue.

I am working with **liveDataset** and for each row I need to **subset** controlDataset and add this subset bellow the liveDataset.

The condition applied in this handmade example is like

```
controlDataset %>%
   filter(
     Value1 < liveDataset$Value1 & Value2 < liveDataset$Value2
     )
```

What am I struggling with all approaches I have tested is that does not work for each row separately (rowwise didnt help or dunno how to use it properly).

Another issue is with **desired GroupId** because I really cannot imagine now how to handle this without looping.

Any ideas?

PS: I need to have the original row from liveDataset as first within the group (or give it another tag/id to be able define what was originally in liveDataset and what was not).

Thank you in advance,
any help really appreciated.

Otto

Comment: Hi @Bury. Please, check `desiredOutput[20, ]`. For `liveDataset[4, ]`, where value1 = 108 and value2 = 103, `controlDataset[6, ], value1 = 95 and value2 = 104 (edit), should not have been included. I'll post an answer bellow.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)


map_dfr(1:nrow(liveDataset), \(x) bind_rows(liveDataset |> slice(x),
                                            controlDataset |> filter(Value1 < liveDataset$Value1[x] & Value2 < liveDataset$Value2[x])) |> 
          mutate(GroupId = x, .before = 1))

   GroupId Value1 Value2 PredValues
1        1    100    105        0.7
2        1     98    100        1.0
3        1     85     90       -2.0
4        1     95    104       -0.3
5        2    110    108        1.6
6        2     98    100        1.0
7        2    109    103        0.5
8        2     85     90       -2.0
9        2     95    104       -0.3
10       3    115    118        1.3
11       3     98    100        1.0
12       3    111    108        2.0
13       3    114    115        1.0
14       3    109    103        0.5
15       3     85     90       -2.0
16       3     95    104       -0.3
17       4    108    103        0.1
18       4     98    100        1.0
19       4     85     90       -2.0
20       5     90     94        0.4
21       5     85     90       -2.0
22       6     95    104       -0.6
23       6     85     90       -2.0
```

I return one less row that you did in your desired output, the last one for GroupId 4, but I am not sure that one should be included since 104>103?

Comment: Hi, thank you for putting time and effort into it!
Well your output is correct, my mistake - handmade table. 

Getting 
```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `&...`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 19500 or 1, not size 0.
```
on my original data, but I will give it more time to find the issue and let you know. 

Thank you again.

Comment: Oh,my answer would be the same from @Lennyy. Too fast!

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you might start from here and develop a more concise approach:

**Newer**

With `lapply` + `rbind`:

```r
liveDataset$GroupId = nseq = seq_len(nrow(liveDataset))
lapply(nseq, \(i) rbind(liveDataset[i, ], with(liveDataset, controlDataset[
  controlDataset$Value1 < Value1[[i]] & controlDataset$Value2 < Value2[[i]], ] |> 
    transform(GroupId = i)))) |> do.call(what = rbind)
```

gives

```r
   Value1 Value2 PredValues GroupId
1     100    105        0.7       1
2      98    100        1.0       1
3      85     90       -2.0       1
4      95    104       -0.3       1
5     110    108        1.6       2
6      98    100        1.0       2
7     109    103        0.5       2
8      85     90       -2.0       2
9      95    104       -0.3       2
10    115    118        1.3       3
11     98    100        1.0       3
12    111    108        2.0       3
13    114    115        1.0       3
14    109    103        0.5       3
15     85     90       -2.0       3
16     95    104       -0.3       3
17    108    103        0.1       4
18     98    100        1.0       4
19     85     90       -2.0       4
20     90     94        0.4       5
21     85     90       -2.0       5
22     95    104       -0.6       6
23     85     90       -2.0       6
```

**Old**

```r
liveDataset$GroupId = nseq = seq_len(nrow(liveDataset))
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(rbind, list(split(liveDataset, nseq), lapply(nseq, \(i) { with(liveDataset,
    controlDataset[controlDataset$Value1 < Value1[[i]] & controlDataset$Value2 < Value2[[i]], ]) |>
    transform(GroupId = i) }) )))) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this actually works but unfortnutely still slower than my previous solution ... but learned a lot thanks to all answers here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the each row, use non-equi join...

```
liveDataset %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  left_join(controlDataset, join_by(Value1 > Value1, Value2 > Value2))%>%
  reframe(bind_rows(across(contains(".x"), first,.names = "{str_remove(col,'.x')}"), 
                    across(contains(".y"), .names = "{str_remove(col, '.y')}")),
          .by = rowid)

   rowid Value1 Value2 PredValues
1      1    100    105        0.7
2      1     98    100        1.0
3      1     85     90       -2.0
4      1     95    104       -0.3
5      2    110    108        1.6
6      2     98    100        1.0
7      2    109    103        0.5
8      2     85     90       -2.0
9      2     95    104       -0.3
10     3    115    118        1.3
11     3     98    100        1.0
12     3    111    108        2.0
13     3    114    115        1.0
14     3    109    103        0.5
15     3     85     90       -2.0
16     3     95    104       -0.3
17     4    108    103        0.1
18     4     98    100        1.0
19     4     85     90       -2.0
20     5     90     94        0.4
21     5     85     90       -2.0
22     6     95    104       -0.6
23     6     85     90       -2.0
```

Note that the `reframe` part is just for reordering and restructuring, otherwise `left_join` does the job quite easily

Comment: Thank you a lot, this actually works but unfortnutely still slower than my previous solution ... but learned a lot thanks to all answers here. Thank you